# PDF Right to left Reading in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am currently working on an Arabic iPhone application which has PDF files to read. I am currently using vfr/Reader open source reader which works as per expectations. Now the client wants the PDF documents to be read (scrolled) from right to left . I tried everything but couldn’t get it. Can someone please lead me to in right direction or share some sample code.

Comment: This is ugly but it may help: reverse the document pages order and show the document from the last page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution for PDF file reading. if you're building an enterprise app that needs annotations and text highlighting or a Newsstand magazine with page curl transitions, PSPDFKit can help you. see this demo

https://github.com/PSPDFKit/PSPDFKit-Demo